# How to change the first day of week on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: internationalization

I want to use the en_US locale but I want to change the first day of week from Sunday to Monday. I have found a way to do this for older versions of Ubuntu but it seems that the configuration has changed recently with Ubuntu 22.04.

When I open `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US` I see the following under `LC_TIME`:

```
LC_TIME
abday   "Sun";"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat"
day "Sunday";/
    "Monday";/
    "Tuesday";/
    "Wednesday";/
    "Thursday";/
    "Friday";/
    "Saturday"

week 7;19971130;1
abmon   "Jan";"Feb";/
    "Mar";"Apr";/
    "May";"Jun";/
    "Jul";"Aug";/
    "Sep";"Oct";/
    "Nov";"Dec"
mon "January";/
    "February";/
    "March";/
    "April";/
    "May";/
    "June";/
    "July";/
    "August";/
    "September";/
    "October";/
    "November";/
    "December"
```

Can I simply change the order of `abday` and `day`? What is `week` and do I need to change it also?

Is this even the correct way to do it?

Comment: `$ less /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE` -> `first_weekday 2` just before `END LC_TIME` - copy `en_US` to a new file, then look at https://superuser.com/a/1750342/346288 to see how to enable it.

Comment: @Hannu that didn't work for me. I added `first_weekday 2` just before `END LC_TIME` but the the calendar still shows Sunday as the first day. I logged out and back in after that.

Comment: Wicked, I know I had that working - it isn't now, can't re-create what I wrote. :-(

Comment: @Hannu: That superuser answer does not work since the new locale name is neither in `/etc/locale.gen` nor `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`. But besides that, a locale name which doesn't follow the pattern `ll_CC.UTF-8@modifier` is deemed to be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

I would edit the existing locale directly.

1. Open `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US` for editing.
2. Add the line

   ```
   first_weekday 2
   ```

   right before the line

   ```
   END LC_TIME
   ```
3. Save.
4. Generate the modified locale:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
   ```

Comment: You should also run ```sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8```